# Is it possible to add characters (instead replace defaults) for string.Trim()?

Tags: c#, .net, trim

I wanted to do trim by default white-space characters and by my additional characters. And I did this by following way:

```
string MyTrim(string source)
{
    char[] badChars = { '!', '?', '#' };
    var result = source.Trim().Trim(badChars);
    return result == source
         ? result
         : MyTrim(result);
}
```

As for me it is looks like stupid, because it has more iterations than it needs.  Is it possible to add characters (instead replace defaults) for string.Trim()? Or where can I found array of 'default white-space characters' which is using in string.Trim() by default? It's sounds easy but I cannot found.

Comment: [Starting with the .NET Framework 4, the method trims all Unicode white-space characters (that is, characters that produce a true return value when they are passed to the Char.IsWhiteSpace method)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx). See also [Wiki: Whitespace character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character#Unicode)

Comment: @CodeCaster, I think you are missing the point, OP wants to avoid using multiple `Trim` calls.

Comment: @Habib I was answering _"where can I found array of 'default white-space characters'?"_.

Comment: I don't think you'll get any less iterations because you will just be iterating over the same characters in the one trim call instead of two

Comment: @CodeCaster, oh right.

Comment: Why are you calling `MyTrim` recursively? Looks like you're worrying about extra `Trim` call, but your own code makes things even worse.

Comment: @Dennis, It isn't really performance problem, just trying to find simple .Net possibility for.

Comment: @Sayse It isn't really performance problem, just trying to find simple .Net possibility for.

Comment: @Dennis, Sorry, previous comment (notified you) isn't finished ...for call trim with additional characters without new logic implementation.

Comment: @Sayse, Sorry, previous comment (notified you) isn't finished ...for call trim with additional characters without new logic implementation.

Comment: You could use two regexs: `"@\A[\s!#?]*"` for the start and `@"[\s!#?]*\Z"` for the end

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to change the default behavior of `Trim`.

You can, however, if you must, create an array containing all the characters you want trimmed so that you can reduce the calls down to just one call, however it would be something like this:

```
var badChars =
    (from codepoint in Enumerable.Range(0, 65536)
     let ch = (char)codepoint
     where char.IsWhiteSpace(ch)
           || ch == '!' || ch == '?' || ch == '#'
     select ch).ToArray();
```

This will give you 1 call to `Trim`:

```
var result = source.Trim(badChars);
```

Ideally you would store that `badChars` somewhere so you don't have to build it all the time.

Now, will this be faster than two calls? I don't know, but I would measure it if necessary.

Comment: Or the OP could iterate the input string `source` to find the white space characters and then remove them, instead of going for 0 to 65536. Although the performance difference would be negligible.

Comment: An additional warning for premature optimization is welcome. While `Trim().Trim(additionalChars)` may "loop stupid" (OP's words), finding this code in some codebase will look more stupid and will definitely make the "wtfs per minute" skyrocket. Unless you're trimming thousands of string per second, you won't notice the difference, in which case readability is more important.

Comment: Ah, code in the question is recursive, ok. Then I'm not so sure about what I would recommend.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It is not only 2 calls, for example "a ! ! ! ! ! ! ! " - 15. It isn't really performance problem, just trying to find simple .Net possibility for.

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry,
...for call trim with additional characters without new logic implementation.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Sorry, previous comment (notified you) isn't finished ...for call trim with additional characters without new logic implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to add additional characters directly.

However, the list of whitespace characters is defined [here in the remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.iswhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) and you could create a static helper list from all the enums provided.

Unless you are parsing enormous strings, it is probably not worth the effort to save a second pass on the string.